# car: contract violation expected: pair? given: () during remove in binary search tree

Tags: scheme

I don't understand how I am getting a contract violation. It seems when I create a bst it doesnt make 2 empty lists it just has ().

This is my remove method:

```
;Returns the binary search tree representing bst after removing x where f and g are predicates as defined in bst-contains.
    (define (bst-remove bst f g x)
      ;if empty return empty
      (cond ((empty? bst) (bst-create-empty)))
      ;else if equal then check right if right is empty then pull from left
      (cond ((g (car bst) x) (cond ((empty? (caddr bst)) (cond ((empty? (cadr bst)) (bst-create-empty))
                                                               (else (car(cadr bst)))))
                                   ;if right isnt empty then remove from left
                                   (else(bst-create (bst-max-right (caddr bst)) (cadr bst) (bst-remove (caddr bst) f g (bst-max-right (caddr bst))))))) 
                             (else (bst-create (car bst) (bst-remove (cadr bst) f g x) (bst-remove (caddr bst) f g x)))))
```

My bst-create and bst-create-empty:

```
;Returns an empty binary search tree.
(define (bst-create-empty)
  '())

;Returns a binary search tree having the specified root value, with left-subtree left and right-subtree right.
(define (bst-create root left right)
  (list root left right))
```

The code I give it is

```
(bst-remove (bst-create 5 (bst-create 6 (bst-create-empty) (bst-create-empty)) (bst-create 4 (bst-create-empty) (bst-create-empty))) < = 6)
```

The error i get is car: contract violation expected: pair? given: ()

Answer (score 2):

You have got Scheme and especially `cond` all wrong. If you in a body of a procedure have two statements like:

```
(define (test lst)
  first-expression
  tail-expression)
```

It is obvious that the `tail-expression` will follow the evaluation and discarding of any result of the `first-expression`. Also unless `first-expression` has side effects it is dead code.  Your `cond` expressions  `(cond ((empty? bst) (bst-create-empty)))` is dead code since no matter what the outcome is it will never be a part of the result since Scheme will evaluate the second `cond` unconditionally. It does `(car bst)` which throws the error.

```
The correct way to have multiple returns are by one expression:

(cond 
  (test1 consequent1)
  (test2 consequent2)
  (test3 consequent3)
  (else alternative))
```

Needless to say all the previous tests are negative so if `test3` is true, then you know that `test1` and `test2` both had negative results. You also know that if `consequent1` is evaluated no other terms or tests gets evaluated. It stops at the first prositive.

In you specific case the code could have looked like this:

```
(define (bst-remove bst f g x)
  (cond ((empty? bst)
         (bst-create-empty))
        ((not (g (car bst) x))
         (bst-create (car bst) (bst-remove (cadr bst) f g x) (bst-remove (caddr bst) f g x)))
        ((not (empty? (caddr bst)))
         (bst-create (bst-max-right (caddr bst)) (cadr bst) (bst-remove (caddr bst) f g (bst-max-right (caddr bst)))))
        ((empty? (cadr bst))
         (bst-create-empty))
        (else
         (caadr bst))))
```

Using nested `if` works too, but it makes harder to read code just like your nested `cond`. Notice that I negated some of the tests since they only have *one* alternative but several tests in its consequent. By negating I could have one consequent and continue testing for the other cases in the same `cond`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've misunderstood `cond`, or possibly Scheme in general.

The result of a function application is the value of the last expression in the function's body (the only reason for having more than one is if you're doing something that has a side effect), and `cond` expressions are evaluated in exactly the same way as other Scheme expressions.

So the expression `(cond ((empty? bst) (bst-create-empty)))` does not *return* an empty tree, it is evaluated and produces an empty tree, and that tree is discarded.
Then evaluation continues with the next `cond`, which is a bad idea when the tree is empty.

A further problem is that the function should produce a tree, but `(car (cadr bst))` wouldn't.

If you define a few useful accessor functions:

```
(define bst-value car)
(define bst-left cadr)
(define bst-right caddr)
```

then these lines are more obviously wrong:

```
(cond ((empty? (bst-left bst)) (bst-create-empty))
       (else (bst-value (bst-left bst)))))
```

Fixing it, it becomes (reasonably) clear that the entire expression

```
(cond ((empty? (bst-left bst)) (bst-create-empty))
       (else (bst-left bst))))
```

is equivalent to

```
(bst-left bst)
```

Now you have

```
(cond ((empty? (bst-right bst)) (bst-left bst))
      ( else make a tree...
```

But there's a lack of symmetry here; surely, if the left subtree is empty, the result should be the entire right subtree in a similar way.

So,

```
(cond ((empty? (bst-right bst)) (bst-left bst))
       (empty? (bst-left bst)) (bst-right bst))
       ( else make a tree...
```

But now we can spot another problem: even in these cases, we need to recurse into the subtrees before we're done.

I'll digress here because too many accessor repetitions and `cond`s makes code pretty unreadable.

Using a couple of `let`s (and getting rid of the unused `f` parameter), I ended up with this:

```
(define (bst-remove tree g x)
  (if (empty? tree)
      (bst-create-empty)
      ;; If the tree isn't empty, we need to recurse.
      ;; This work is identical for all the cases below, so
      ;; lift it up here.
      (let ([new-left  (bst-remove (bst-left tree) g x)]
            [new-right (bst-remove (bst-right tree) g x)])
        ;; Build an appropriate tree with the new subtrees.
        (if (g (bst-value tree) x)
            (cond [(empty? new-left) new-right] ;; If either new subtree is empty,
                  [(empty? new-right) new-left] ;;  use the other.
                  ;; The complicated case. Get the new node value from the
                  ;; right subtree and remove it from there before using it.
                  [else (let ([new-value (bst-max-right new-right)])
                           (bst-create new-value
                                       new-left
                                       (bst-remove new-right g new-value)))])
            ;; The straightforward case.
            (bst-create (bst-value tree) 
                         new-left 
                         new-right)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You refer to your second `cond` as an `else if` in your comment, but it's not an else-if, it's just an if. That is, you check the second condition even if the first one was true, in which case the `car` part of the condition causes this error.

To fix this, you should make both conditions part of a single `cond`, in which case it will actually act like an `else if`.